# Where is the basic Control-TAB (MRU) behavior in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, editor, text-editor, tabs, mru

In most multi-document editors for windowing environments, <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> will utilize an MRU list to bring the user back to the last visible file.  What is the appropriate command to accomplish this in Xcode 3.x?

I currently have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> mapped to "View|Previous File", however this does not appear to be an MRU. Worse yet, if it hits the "beginning" of the list (should be a circular buffer), it falls back on inserting an actual TAB character into the text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Xcode Version 3, there isn't anything that's exactly like the MRU you describe - however, check out the discussion on [this page](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/248756-how-is-your-xcode-layout-and-workflow.html) for some options that will get you closer to the behavior you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, this didn't lead me closer to understanding whether there is actual support for an MRU of files in XCode.

Comment: Oh, I should have prefixed it with "as of Xcode version 3, no, but"

Answer (score 3):

In recent XCode (10.3), when in a code editor press:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>

Then use <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> keys and <kbd>enter</kbd>
to select from the MRU sorted list of recent files.

There is even an option to increase the size of the history.

Comment: So this functionality does exist in xCode.  Someone experienced with the autohotkey equivalents in mac could write a macro so that ctrl+tab could simulate this behavior in xcode.

Comment: @kwaalaateimaa I think the problem with asking for this feature is that it has been a point of contention between macOS and Windows users for a long long time. I get the impression that it's one of those things that Apple refuse to consider just for petty, childish reasons. (A bit like the BSOD Finder icon for SMB servers.)

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 3 (or any Mac application) you can use Command-Tilde (⌘~) to switch between open windows.

In Xcode 4 you use ⌘} for next tab and ⌘{ for previous tab - command shift bracket.

As a side note, for some reason Xcode 4 won't let me set the key binding for previous/next tab to the standard Control-Tab.  When I try it puts in Command-Control-Tab.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Anthony.  In my question I'm asking specifically about Control-TAB, (in window document/buffer switching) behavior.  Command-Tilde (⌘~) is quite useful for other purposes, though, I agree!

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what you're asking.  Are you talking about how XCode allows you to navigate forward/backward document history in a single document window like a browser?  (Command-Option-LeftArrow and Command-Option-RightArrow)

Comment: Yes, except that functionality handles cursor navigation as well as document navigation.  The standard Ctrl-TAB behavior in well-written MDI Windows applications is that Ctrl-TAB behaves like an MRU on documents, or tabbed windows.  I'm looking for that behavior, not cursor movement.

Comment: Then to answer your question, there is no such behavior or command in Xcode3.