# Keyboard shortcut to toggle between previous file and current file in editor

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, xcode4.3

I usually use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to toggle between last viewed tab or file and current one in other editors like VS or Netbeans or even on browsers. But with xcode I cannot find a keyboard combo for that. I have googled with no avail.

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the basic Control-TAB (MRU) behavior in XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563125/where-is-the-basic-control-tab-mru-behavior-in-xcode)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can navigate forward and back with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>