# Is there a single keyboard shortcut to switch between the two most recently visited tabs in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

When I'm coding I often like to jump back and forth between the two most recently visited open tabs in an IDE. Is there any *single* keyboard shortcut in Xcode for that?

In e.g. Android Studio for macOS you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to achieve this like in many other IDEs (and analogously, switching between the two most recently visited applications in macOS is achieved by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>). But if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> once in Xcode and then do it again later, I don't jump back and forth between the two most recently opened tabs. Instead I continue through all the opened tabs in Xcode in a circle.

I know I can alter between pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to circle forward and backward between all opened tabs but that is not what I want since that doesn't necessarily switch between the two most recently visited tabs, instead always between the two most adjacent tabs. Also, I need to remember if I held down <kbd>Shift</kbd> or not the last time I used the keyboard shortcut to avoid ending up in some other tab if I have more than two tabs open.

Comment: Try command + `. (command +Grave key - which has tilde in its top, near to number key 1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the basic Control-TAB (MRU) behavior in XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563125/where-is-the-basic-control-tab-mru-behavior-in-xcode)